# How can I find the origin temporary redirect URL in my current URL page?

Tags: javascript, http, http-status-code-302

You see my requests below:

[image]

[image]

---

There have two HTTP requests, in my browser(initial URL is: `http://102.24.5.7/dedicated_servers`) I request the first URL, you can see there is `bw=20M` param I added in the URI.

but in the website it redirect to the second URL(`cart.php?a=confproduct&i=4`).

now, in the page `cart.php?a=confproduct&i=4`, how can I get the URL which redirect to current URL?(I mean find the `cart.php?a=add&pid=8&carttpl=McSpace&bw=20M`) , I want to get the `bw=20M` param.

---

**EDIT-01**

In the `cart.php?a=confproduct&i=4` link when I get `document.referrer`, it shows `http://102.24.5.7/dedicated_servers`, can not the URL `cart.php?a=add&pid=8&carttpl=McSpace&bw=20M`.

Comment: If it is redirected you could try to get it using `document.referrer` (javascript)

Comment: No, _don’t_ use the referrer, if you want something that will actually work “in the wild.” // Is this about code you have written yourself? Then either pass the GET parameter along with the redirect, or store it into the session … which one of those makes more sense, depends on what actually needs to be achieved here.

Comment: I can only add code in the `cart.php?a=confproduct&i=4`, I mean I only can write code in the second page to get the first URL, but I don't know how.